# Trying to configure mpdf plugin in cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to configure mPDF to following **https://github.com/segy/Mpdf** in cakephp 2. But while accessing the mpdf class I am getting error *The application is trying to load a file from the Mpdf plugin*. I have put the mpdf folder under Vendor.
Let me know where I am missing in configuration.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands, log data or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link: https://github.com/segy/Mpdf/issues/6
Segy suggest:

> You need to have mpdf in your vendor folder. So download it from
>   http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download and copy it to your
>   vendor folder